# Classification of separable rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, separable-extension

Let $C$ be a symmetric monoidal category. A unital associative algebra $(A,m:A\otimes A\to A)$ is called **separable** if there exists an $A$-$A$-bimodule homomorphism $d: A\to A\otimes A$ such that $m\circ d =\mathrm{id}_A$.

When we consider the category $\mathrm{Vect}_k$ of $k$-vector spaces for some field $k$ whose symmetric monoidal structure is given by the relative tensor product $\otimes_{k}$, the separable algebras defined above in $\mathrm{Vect}_k$ concides with the separable algebras that appear in separable field extensions over $k$. And for such seprable $k$-algebras, we have a lot of fruitful results.

Now, note that the category $\mathrm{Abel}$ of abelian groups also has a symmetric monoidal structure given by $\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}$. So it is natural to ask what are separable algebras in $\mathrm{Abel}$. Recall that a unital associative algebra in $\mathrm{Abel}$ is a unital ring. Hence the question is to classify all separable (unital) rings.

Can someone provide some result about this quesion?

What I know is that the integer ring itself is separable, which is obvious, and the field of complex numbers is also separable. And I saw an answer of [Classifiation of separable algebras over a commutative ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868771/classification-of-separable-algebras-over-a-commutative-ring?rq=1), maybe we can use the results mentioned in that answer to solve this problem.

Moreover, there is a notion called the "separable ring extension", does this notion has some relation to the separable rings as the separable algebras over a field is equivent to separable extensions?